# Problem retrieving values from JSON object

Tags: jquery, json

I am having a little trouble retrieving the values from a JSON object that is returned after a jQuery GET request and I am hoping someone here will be able to help. I think I may be doing something stupid but cannot figure it out.

In firebug the response is show as:

```
[{"plan_id":"2","plan_name":"plan 2","plan_desc":"plan 2 desc"}]
```

However when I try to retrieve the values they are undefined.

Here is the code I am using:

```
jQuery(function(){
jQuery("#add_plan").click(function(){
var val = jQuery("#plan_id").val();
if (!isNaN(val))
{
      jQuery.ajax({
      success: function(data) {
        if (data)
        {

         jQuery("#plan-list").append(
"<li>"
+ " <label for=\"plans\">" + data.plan_name + "</label>"
+ "</li>"
); 
        }
      },
      type: 'GET',
          dataType: 'json',
          url: 'http://example.com/plans.php?plan=' + val 
      });
}
});
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it's an array, you need `data[0].plan_name` instead, or possibly a loop like this if you expect multiple results:

```
$.each(data, function() {
  $("<label for='plans' />").text(this.plan_name).wrap("<li />").parent()
    .appendTo("#plan-list");
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/9CKAP/).

Answer (score 3):

Looking closely, your JSON result

```
[{...}]
```

is an object (`{}`) inside an array (`[]`).

You will be able to access the values using

```
data[0].plan_name
```

Answer (score 0):

The above posters are correct, but don't assume there will always be an Array, test the value of data every time.  If it's an object, proceed.  If it's an object/array loop.